# How to copy a row of values from a 2D array into a 1D array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

We have the following object

```
int [,] oGridCells;
```

which is only used with a fixed first index

```
int iIndex = 5;
for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < iUpperBound; iLoop++)
{
  //Get the value from the 2D array
  iValue = oGridCells[iIndex, iLoop];

  //Do something with iValue
}
```

Is there a way in .NET to convert the values at a fixed first index into a single dimension array (other than by looping the values)?

I doubt it would speed up the code (and it may well make it slower) if the array is only being looped once. But if the array was being heavily manipulated then a single dimension array would be more efficient than a multi dimension array.

My main reason for asking the question is to see if it can be done and how, rather than using it for production code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following code demonstrates copying 16 bytes (4 ints) from a 2-D array to a 1-D array.

```
int[,] oGridCells = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
int[] oResult = new int[4];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(oGridCells, 0, oResult, 0, 16);
```

You can also selectively copy just 1 row from the array by providing the correct byte offsets. This example copies the middle row of a 3-row 2-D array.

```
int[,] oGridCells = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
int[] oResult = new int[2];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(oGridCells, 8, oResult, 0, 8);
```

Comment: This doesn't acheive the results required as it copies all the values, not just the values from first index 0 or 1.

Comment: I added an example to copy 1 row.

Comment: To use this method you would need to calculate the bounds of the array to get the offset. This something that is inefficient for multi dimension arrays. But it does look like it would work.

Comment: What's inefficient about it? The size of the element times the number of elements per row times the row index is the offset.  And you only have to calculate the offset once if your row index doesn't change.

Comment: Agreed, I guess that you would have to call the inefficient method to find the upper bounds to be able to loop through the elements as in the question source code. Your code doesn't look quite right though, your array is int [2, 3] so one row of data would be int[3] at either index 0 or 1.

Comment: As demonstrated by "Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", oGridCells[0, 1], oGridCells[1, 0]);" the first index refers to the row number and the second index refers to the column number.  My array is int[3,2], you have to declare it as int[,] oGridCells = new int[3,2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };.  If you try to use 2,3 you get an error.

Comment: Hey, this is exactly the answer you asked for isn't it?  Have you checked it out?

Comment: No this is not what I asked for. I want all the column values for a single row, as the question code shows by using a fixed first index.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
 int[,] twoD = new int[2,2];
 twoD[0, 0] = 1;
 twoD[0, 1] = 2;
 twoD[1, 0] = 3;
 twoD[1, 1] = 4;

 int[] result = twoD.Cast<int>().Select(c => c).ToArray();
```

The result will be an integer array with data:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Why do you use Select?

Comment: You can remove select if you want to, it still okay.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

I realized there is a way!  Granted, it's probably not worth it.  Use [unsafe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code).  Full example, showing both ways, with unsafe below:

```
public class MultiSingleUnsafe
{
    public static unsafe void Main(String[] a)
    {
    int rowCount = 6;
    int iUpperBound = 10;
    int [,] oGridCells = new int[rowCount, iUpperBound];

    int iIndex = rowCount - 2; // Pick a row.

    for(int i = 0; i < iUpperBound; i++)
    {
        oGridCells[iIndex, i] = i;
    }

    for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < iUpperBound; iLoop++)
    {
        //Get the value from the 2D array
        int iValue = oGridCells[iIndex, iLoop];
        Console.WriteLine("Multi-dim array access iValue: " + iValue);
        //Do something with iValue
    }
    
    fixed(int *lastRow = &(oGridCells[iIndex,0]))
    {   
        for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < iUpperBound; iLoop++)
        {
        int iValue = lastRow[iLoop];
        Console.WriteLine("Pointer access iValue: " + iValue);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

There is no way I know to cast a multiple-dimensional array into a single-dimensional one in C#.  Of course, you could create a new single-dimensional array and copy into it.  But I don't think this will get a performance benefit even if you loop over the values multiple times.  As Daren said, internally it's all pointer arithmetic anyway.  If you want to be certain, profile it.

Comment: I'm not looking for a cast, I know that that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be suprised if it were possible: I bet `oGridCells[iIndex, iLoop]` is just a sort of shorthand (internally, in MSIL) for `oGridCells[iIndex * iLoop]`, and that multidimensional arrays are syntactic sugar for this.

To answer your question: No. You will have to loop the values.

Comment: They are a different type to single dimension arrays. A zero index single dimension array is a vector type while all other arrays are array type. So not syntax sugar.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a reference to each array. You can, however, use a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

Comment: Agreed, if I was re-writing the code (which is not an option) I would make use of jagged arrays. Especially as jagged arrays have an improved performance over multi dimension arrays.

Answer (score 1):

"But if the array was being heavily manipulated then a single dimension array would be more efficient than a multi dimension array."

I did some profiling of exactly this last summer and was surprised to see no significant difference in performance between a 2D and 1D array.

I didn't test the performance of a jagged array.

Comment: They are different types, certain operations (e.g. testing the length) can be significantly slower. A jagged array offers the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's about 30% faster to use `Span.CopyTo` on .NET Core and .NET 5+, than to use `Buffer.BlockCopy` as in [@BlueMonkMN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797383/14868997).

```cs
public static T[] CopyToArray<T>(ref T start, int length)
{
    var target = new T[length];
    var span = MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref start, length);
    span.CopyTo(target.AsSpan());
    return target;
}
```

You would use it like this (obviously ensure you don't overrun the array, as there are no bounds checks).

```cs
var singleArray = CopyToArray(ref oGridCells[0, 0], oGridCells.Length);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mLJnLR)

**BenchmarkDotNet results**

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [BlueMonkMN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797383/14868997) | 18.84 ns | 0.220 ns | 0.206 ns |
| Charlieface | 12.31 ns | 0.196 ns | 0.183 ns |

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: Compared to the accepted answer, sorry thought that was obvious from the benchmark