# How to turn a 3D array into multiple 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of values in a 3-D array, stored as [x,y,z]. A 3-D array is useful for the previous function, but in the current function, I would like z series' of [x,y] arrays. Is this possible? The array I have is `input[x,y,z]`, and I would like it to be redone into 2-D arrays. x and y are the values for the 2-D array.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, double[,]>();
for (int files = 0; files < input.GetLength(2); files++)
{
    dict[files] = input[x,y,files]
}
```

Comment: Say z is 3 long. What I want is 3  2-D arrays of values

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  A three dimensional array IS multiple two dimensional arrays.

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to call them separately( eg. dict[0], dict[1], ...etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure what your data structure is describing. Do you have an array set up like myArray[X][Y][Z]?

Comment: Here is the function, where input is declared.        public static double[,] translateData( double[, ,] input )

Comment: Yes, but your structure isn't clear. You can have an array of sub-arrays of sub-sub-arrays, or you can have an array that contains sets of values. Your structure feels ambiguous.

Comment: Are your z values unique?  If not a `Dictionary<z, [x,y]>` won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, double[,]>();
for (int files = 0; files < input.GetLength(2); files++)
{
    double[,] twoD = new double[input.GetLength(0), input.GetLength(1)];
    for (int x = 0; x < input.GetLength(0); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < input.GetLength(1); y++)
            twoD[x, y] = input[x, y, files];
    dict.Add(files, twoD);
}
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797354/how-to-copy-a-row-of-values-from-a-2d-array-into-a-1d-array) might help as well.

Note that this does assume that your `z` values are unique.