# object[,] to object[] or object[][] to object[]

Tags: c#, arrays

I try the following. I got data in the following two-dimensioanl buffer array from 2 channels:

```
object[,] buffer;
buffer = new buffer[2,1000000];
```

Now i only want to extract one channel to an one-dimensional array.

```
object[] bufferdata = buffer(1,???);
```

Does somebody know an way to get those data in a new array WITHOUT copying each value of the buffer(1,i) in a loop.
Iam also able to use this kind of two-dimensional array object[][] buffer. Maybe this is bestter to find a solution.

Comment: object[][] to object[] is straight (unless you want to object[m][]) but for object[,] you must copy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a row of values from a 2D array into a 1D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797354/how-to-copy-a-row-of-values-from-a-2d-array-into-a-1d-array)

Comment: Thx, but my question also includes that maybe it is better to use kind of object[][] array to convert into an object[] array without copying.

Comment: If you want to do this without copying then you *have* to create an array of arrays.  So it has to be object[][].  If you do it wrong with object[,] then copying is a hard requirement.

Comment: Cool, so how to copy from object[][] to object[] ?

Comment: You are only copying references, not all the data.

Comment: Yes, that was my question... I only want to copy the ref of the array to an other and not copying in a loop.

Comment: BTW, What do the objects point to?

Comment: I use object as a sample array. I use arrays from type of double.

Answer (score 0):

Going from a 2D array `object[,]` to a 1D array `object[]` is always going to be slow. It helps if you don't use `object` and know what types are stored. `Buffer.BlockCopy()` wont help you because it only works with array of primitives only.

I suggest either storing the buffer in a jagged array `object[][]` per channel and then retrieval is trivial `object[] data = buffer[i]`

Or create a long 1D array of size `2*1000000` and layer the data by channel. Then you can use `Array.Copy()` or maybe `Buffer.BlockCopy()` if you know the types to move either the first `1000000` elements out, or the last `1000000` elements out.