# How are multi-dimensional arrays stored (.Net)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr, coreclr

I have a few questions about how .Net stores multi-dimensional arrays in memory. I am interested in true multi-dimensional arrays not jagged arrays.

How does the Common Language Runtime (CLR) store multi-dimensional arrays? Is it in row-major, column-major, Iliffe vector or some other format?

Is this format required by the Common Language Infrastucture (CLI) or any other specification?

Is it likely to vary over time or between platforms?

Comment: You can start with the specification, though I don't have time to check if it answers your specific question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/arrays

Comment: I expect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797383/3181933) ([result](https://rextester.com/CQOVE99093)) tells you something about how they are structured in memory though.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to vary over time given the convergence on C-heritage languages.  Note that for COM interop, to my knowledge, COM SafeArrays are stored column-major not row-major (as COM followed classic VB which followed Fortran in this scheme).  I would expect that the .NET built-in marshaling would normally take care of this.

Comment: @Craig No it's row-major in SAFEARRAY also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-mcis/3aec369a-beb8-407f-995e-ee4d94666ea4 see the last paragraph

Comment: @Charlieface The sequence shown in the last paragraph is exactly what I would expect for column-major, not row-major.  The example is organized in memory as c1r1, c1r2, c2r1, c2r2, ... so that the natural addition without completely re-organizing the array is to add another column.

Comment: I would expect in .NET, the layout would be r1c1, r1c2, r2c1, r2c2, ...

Comment: @Craig Sorry looks like you're right, misunderstood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the specification [ECMA-335 Partition I](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf) *(my bold)*

> **8.9.1 Array types**
>
> Array elements shall be laid out within the array object **in row-major order** (i.e., the elements associated with the rightmost array dimension shall be laid out contiguously from lowest to highest index). The actual storage allocated for each array element can include platform-specific padding. (The size of this storage, in bytes, is returned by the `sizeof` instruction when it is applied to the type of that array‘s elements.)

Section 14.2 also has more explanation.

These two sections specifically refer to **arrays** as opposed to **vectors**, the latter of which is the more familiar zero-based one-dimensional array used in most places.

Arrays on the other hand, can be multi-dimensional and based on any bound, they can also be one-dimensional.

So essentially, it's just one big array under the hood, and uses simple math to calculate offsets.

---

*"Is it likely to vary over time or between platforms?"* I'll get my crystal ball out... The spec can always change, and implementations may decide to derogate from it.

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know it's in the spec and not just an implementation detail.